# Using RaspiBackup and Buffalo Terastation TS1200D NAS

Tags: permissions, nfs, raspberry-pi4, nas

On my Raspberry PI, I have set up the mount of an NFS drive on a Buffalo Terastation. I cannot see what version of NFS this has installed but the UI does not have options for Guest Permission.

The mount works on the Raspberry PI and I can see the relevant files and folders.

However, RasppiBackup returns a "RBK0266E: Access rights missing to create fileattributes on %s (Filesystem: %s)." message. The description of this message suggests the following:

> Usually it means the nfs partition was not exported with no_root_squash on the nfs server. This option has to be used in  /etc/exports on the NFS Server for the exported partition. In addition the filesystem used has to support Linux fileattributes -  either ext3 or ext4. ntfs or fat32 doesn't work.

Reading up on this a little more, the Guest Permission seems to be the option to be disabled on later Terastation models and this would set no_root_squash.

Have I understood this correctly and, if so, is there any way around this given the model of Terastation?

For info, my pi is running on Bullseye.